# How to resolve a need for a static method in an interface?

Tags: java, json

I have 2 classes: Rectangle and Circle.

Each of them implements the interface "JSONSerializable" with the methods "import" and "export".

In order to differentiate between the two classes the interface has a third method "getType" which simply returns "rectangle" or "circle" depending on the class.

This works fine and i get a JSON String which looks something like this:

```
{
    type:rectangle,
    points:[{1,2},{2,2},{2,1},{1,1}]
}
```

When i read the String again i need to decide which import method to call, depending on the type. What I did now is this:

```
public enum JSONType{
    Rectangle(Rectangle.getStaticType()),
    Circle(Circle.getStaticType());

    private final String type;

    JSONType(String type){
        this.type = type;
    }

    public String getType(){
        return type;
    }
}
```

This works, i can then read the JSON-String and compare against all String types in my enum. However, I need to declare two methods (getType() and static getStaticType()) for every child objects, where both return the same String:

```
public static String getStaticType(){
    return "rectangle";
}

public String getType(){
    return Rectangle.getStaticType();
}
```

Is there any way around that? I think the answere is no, but I've never before had a situation like this. I'm happy for any design advice :)

Comment: *"In order to differentiate between the two classes"* You have a broken design. You should never have a situation where you need to make a decision based on the *class* of an object. This is the basic point in OOP in general and *polymorphism* in particular.

Comment: I don't use the getType method to differentiate between objects in the code, only when I write them to JSON. At some point I need to write the class (or in this case, a type) into the JSON file, otherwise I can't differentiate between classes when I read them.

Comment: @FranzFranz, what if you reverted this so `Rectangle.getType()` returns `ShapeType.RECTANGLE` or `ShapeType.RECTANGLE.type()`? Then you wouldn't need two methods, only enum one.

Comment: @M.Prokhorov, I did not think about that, works perfectly! Thank you very much. If you bother to write it up in a separate answer i'm going to accept it.